# Calculating Median and Midpoint from File IO

Tags: python

So I have this code that creates a file and gets input from the user. Then what is supposed to happen is they get options of things to do such as calculate the mean, median, mode, and delete inputs,etc. However, I can not figure out how to calculate most of the things and I was wondering if someone could help me with how I would calculate the Median and Midpoint from inputs that are taken from a file

```
def computing_Median(filename):           

    with open(filename,"r") as fout:
        for line in fout.readlines():
            ordered = sorted(float(filename))
            length = len(float(filename))
    print("The median of this list is:")
    print(float((ordered[length//2] + ordered[-(length+1)//2]))/2)

    main(filename)

def computing_Midpoint(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as fout:
        filename.sort(key=int)
        minNum = min(float(filename))
        maxNum = max(float(filename))
        print("The midpoint of this list is:")
        print((minNum + maxNum) / 2)

    main(filename)
```

Comment: I think you're getting downvoted because the code is way too long, and the question is too vague. For example, if your question concerns the calculation of the standard deviation, can you write a small piece of code (10 lines) reproducing the problem? then I will be happy to help.

Comment: Okay shortened my code up sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't make sense to me. for example you are trying to case filename (presumably a string, the name of a file) into a float :-/. I think you should write the function, and call it yourself. You need to tell us what is the input to your function, and what happens.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the problem? Are you getting errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Also, I would suggest splitting this into multiple functions - one that takes a filename and returns a list of `float`s, and others that takes a list of `float`s and returns the appropriate summary statistic. This way you don't have to load the file again every time.

Answer (score 3):

Ow.

```
with open(filename,"r") as fout:
    for line in fout.readlines():
        ordered = sorted(float(filename))
        length = len(float(filename))
print("The median of this list is:")
print(float((ordered[length//2] + ordered[-(length+1)//2]))/2)
```

Here's what you're asking Python to do:

1. Open a file.
2. Refer to it as "file OUT", implying you will output to it.
3. Don't output to it, instead read from it.
4. Read all the lines in the file, as text.
5. Take each line as a string of characters and completely ignore it. Instead,

   - take the filename (e.g. "myfile") as a string of characters.
   - Sort the filename into alphabetical order ("efilmy").
   - Read the file's name ("myfile") as a number (this will fail).
   - Imagine you had interpreted "myfile" as a number, get the length of the number (what?).
6. Throw all that away, ignoring the stuff in the file.
7. Do all the nonsense calculation again, over and over.
8. Print the text "the median of this list is".
9. Print *this*:

   - The filename in alphabetical order ("efilmy")
   - ... indexed by
   - ... the length of the non-integer number "efilmy"
   - ... integer divided in half
   - added to
   - ... the filename in alphabetical order ("efilmy")
   - ... indexed backwards by using a negative number
   - ... the length of the non-integer number "efilmy"
   - ... plus one
   - ... integer divided by two
   - all divided by two
   - all reinterpreted as a floating point number
   - ... reinterpreted as a string

Just read that and think "what would a human do if I asked them to do these steps? Is this going to give me the answer I want?".

Your whole code seems to be this kind of "code is just a case of randomly typing things and hoping I hit on something that works" bizarro stuff.

It won't work, it's not close to fixable without rewriting ... all of it.